# Want to know about google map pop ups or snippet upon exact location

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to develop an app on google map that could notify me with some information set by the user when I am close to the exact location. So can I get a link for this that How can I get pop-ups when I am at the exact(user) location?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  First you said 'close to the exact location' (if so, within what distance?), then you said 'at the exact(user) location'.  You will probably never be at the exact location, as your lat/lon may be different if you are 15-30 feet away from the lat/lon of the exact location.  You might want to try to check when the user's location is within, say, 1 mile of the target location.  You can get this information with a call to a Google Map API for getting directions from the current location to the target.  Then, what kind of popups do you want? Map markers?

Comment: Thanks brother...Pop ups means map markers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to enable a location manager to start getting the user's current location.  Then, every time the user's location updates, the location manager calls the onLocationChanged() method.  Here, you would want to check the distance between the user's current location and the destination location.  If they are within whatever distance you choose, then you can display your map marker.  Here is a little example of how to do that:

```
@Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


      float distanceInMeters =  destLocation.distanceTo(location);

      // Distance in miles        
      double distance_to_dest = (distanceInMeters/1609.344);
      int distance_to_dest_int = (int)(distance_to_dest * 100);
      distance_to_dest = ((double)distance_to_dest_int/100.00);

      tvMilesToGo.setText(String.format("%.2f", distance_to_dest) + "mi");

      // About 1/10th of a mile
      if ((distanceInMeters > 149) && (distanceInMeters < 176)) {

          // I played an alarm sound when close to the target destination
          //if (alarmPlayer.isPlaying()) {
          //    alarmPlayer.stop();
          //}   
          //alarmPlayer.start();

            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(destLocation.getLatitude(), destLocation.getLongitude()))
            .title(“Arrived”)
            .snippet(“You have arrived at your destination!”)
            .icon(red_descriptor));

        Marker.showInfoWindow;

      }


  }
```

Note, in your case, you would probably only ever want to add a marker once, so, you would probably want to set a flag such as markerIsVisible = true once you add it to the map, and then check before adding the marker if (markerIsVisible == false) {add the marker, markerIsVisible = true}